# Norm in $L^2$ space

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a brief question regarding the norm of the $L^2$ space defined on an interval $[a,b]$.  On various websites I have seen this defined as:

$$\|f(x)\| = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx$$

However, yesterday I posted a question in which I had to use:

$$\|f(x)\| = \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx}$$

to get the proper answer.  I asked for clarification about this in yesterday's thread, but did not receive an explanation - probably because by the time I inquired about this, my thread was already getting old.  The link to my question from yesterday is:

[Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization for subspace of $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201584/gram-schmidt-orthogonalization-for-subspace-of-l2)

If anyone could please clarify for me exactly why we use the norm definition with a square root in the link above, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the norm's axiom is *semilinearity*:$$\| \lambda x\|=|\lambda| \cdot\| x\|\quad \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \;(\mathrm {or}\;\mathbb{C})$$

Comment: You're absolutely right!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The $L_2$ norm is defined by your second formula:
$$\|f(x)\| = \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx}$$
or, equivalently
$$\|f(x)\|^2 = {\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx}.$$

Your first formula defines a “norm” that doesn't satisfy basic norm properties. In particular, $\|\alpha f\| \neq \alpha \|f\|$ for $\alpha\in {\mathbb R}_{\geq 0}$ (but rather $\|\alpha f\| = \alpha^2 \|f\|$).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I must have visited a shady website, where the first definition was used!  I'm really happy to have this cleared up!  Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Correct definition of $\|f(x)\| $ is not

$$\|f(x)\| = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx$$ but

$$\|f(x)\| = \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 dx}$$

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Infinite-dimensional_case

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yeah, there must have been a typo where I found the first definition.  Really appreciate your answer!